# Mixing sea foam and gumout

Tags: fuel-injectors

I have clogged fuel injectors.  I used gumout in my gas tank and it's not working.  Can I mix sea foam in with it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Yes, you can mix it, *but to what end?* Seafoam will only work well if it can pass through your injectors. If you actually have clogged injectors, they will still remained clogged. There are much better ways of solving your issue, like running carb cleaner through your injectors or taking them to a shop to have them refurbished.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, severely clogged injectors Should just be replaced with new ones. Unofficially, you can get a can of carb soak( comes in a small paint can type container, not "carb cleaner"), remove your injectors, and soak them overnight. Remove any o-rings or rubber fittings or they will swell slightly and can make it a nightmare to fit back in. After they've soaked you can give the opening at each end a spraying with regular carb cleaner and then blow them out with an  air compressor( from a few inches away, you're not trying to make a seal and blow air out the other end, but just bounce it off and loosen whatever may be left in its path) I've had good success with that method but sometimes they're just not fixable, and technically there's a risk of breaking down some types of construction materials used in the injectors, but I've never seen that happen. Clean at your own risk I suppose.